# Firestore - how do I fetch all documents with an empty map field?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firebase Firestore collection called "posts" that has a structure like this:

```
{
    "title": "My blog title",
    "categories": {
        "general": true,
        "sample": true
    }
}
```

I can query for all blog posts with the category "general" like this: `db.collection('posts').where('categories.general', '==', true).get().then()` however, I can't seem to figure out a way to fetch all documents where the "categories" map is empty.

I would like to query all documents in the "posts" collection where `"categories": {}`. I tried `db.collection('posts').where('categories', '==', {}).get().then()` but that didn't work. How would I go about fetching this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying is not possible.  The way Firestore indexes work is with the *presence* of fields in documents, not by the *absence* of fields.  You can only expect to be able to query for things that actually exist.

Comment: Thanks, Doug! Can you recommend an alternate solution or data model that can help me achieve this result?

Comment: You could maintain a count of categories in the document, then query where the count equals zero.

Comment: Good suggestion, will try that! Thank you.